# loadworkbook in R including charts

Tags: r, file-upload, openxlsx

I have an xlsx workbook on my desktop with existing sheets. Some of the sheets includes charts (e.g. line chart). I have a dataframe in R that I would like to write into a sheet in this workbook and then save the workbook. I am using loadworkbook to bring in the file and then writing the data to the correct sheet. After doing this, when I open the workbook, the data writes in correctly, but the sheets with the charts are now blank (the charts aren't preserved). Is there a way to keep them? When I click on the sheets formerly with charts, they are now blank.

I'm using loadworkbook from the openxlsx package

Comment: Please share a reproducible example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example
Share your code or what you have tried so far. So that someone could help you easily

Comment: I suspect you might need to use a different package like XLConnect if you want to edit the data on a sheet while leaving any non-loadable-into-R content like charts alone. I think loadWorkbook loads contents and formatting of cells, but not other excel objects, so what you save won't have those.

Comment: Thank you. I was hoping that loadWorkbook would load any excel content, including excel objects such as bar graphs, pie charts, etc., but if it only loads spreadsheet data and formatting, I will look to a different package.